# Why does the PHP function htmlentities(...) returns wrong results?

Tags: php, html-entities

I have the following code :

```
function testAccents() {
    $str = "àéè";
    $html = htmlentities($str);
    echo $html;
}
```

When I run it, instead of getting `&agrave;&eacute;&egrave;` I get `&Atilde;&nbsp;&Atilde;&copy;&Atilde;&uml;`.

I thought that it could be a problem of encoding but the file is utf-8 :

```
> file -bi PublicationTest.php 
  text/x-c++; charset=utf-8
```

Why do I get this strange result ?

EDIT: I use PHP 5.3.

Comment: It looks like a problem of encoding indeed. Try to re-encode it using notepad++ or TextMate.

Comment: Damn, would've said that the file isn't utf8 encoded. Which version of php are you using? Try using htmlentities ( $str, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8' );

Comment: I thought PHP uses UTF-16 for strings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before PHP 5.4.0, [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) expects ISO-8859-1 data by default. It's interpreting your UTF-8 input as single-byte characters, which results in the funny results you get.

Specify the encoding specifically.

```
$html = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Also some good stuff is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#106929)

Comment: @Dark yes, it's needed only in PHP < 5.4.0.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works fine, only there is no ENT_HTML401 in PHP 5.3, only ENT_COMPAT.

Comment: @Barth ah, then just get rid of that one - I just copy & pasted the  "default" value from the function definition (which seems to apply to 5.4 too, then)