# PHP 5.4 German umlauts / diacritics don't work anymore

Tags: php, diacritics

I have upgraded my website to PHP 5.4 and suddenly German umlauts / diacritics which are written as

```
&ouml;
```

do not work anymore. They just display as `&ouml;` instead of `ö`.

When I go back to PHP 5.3 it works again.

I am preparing the text like this:

```
$thetext = (html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($row[kurztext], ENT_QUOTES)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP 5.4 on, [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/function.htmlentities.php) and [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) are defaulting to 'UTF-8', which probably your data isn't (if it is coming from a database).

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13246958/1947205) for more information.

Note: In that thread, it is just the other way around, so you need to convert your data *to* UTF-8 or tell the function to interpret your data *as* non-UTF-8).

```php
$thetext = (html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($row[kurztext], ENT_QUOTES), ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Additionally, I think you should be able to work without `htmlspecialchars_decode()` now, since `html_entity_decode()` can also take care of the quotes via `ENT_QUOTES`. Just add that additional flag to its parameters (I took the two currently used ones, since they are the PHP default values).

Comment: right, it is coming from a DB. so what is the recommended encoding for the DB and the website?

Comment: @clamp I guess in the long run, everything will become UTF-8 eventually, so switching your database to use UTF-8 might make sense, but you can still work without. You just have to tell the PHP functions to behave accordingly.